# How can I make a gameObject jump quick at first then start slowing down after a while? This code does not work like it's supposed to

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

How can I make a gameObject jump quick at first then start slowing down after a while? This code does not work like it's supposed to. Here's exactly what I want: When the game starts, the gameObject plays an idle animation then "Squat" when the user presses down their finger (Squat is an animation that I made) and Jump (quick at first then slow down after a while, like gravity on the moon, let's say) when they release the finger. That's all! To give you a better view, let's take for example the main character in Crossy Road: when the user presses down, the chicken "squats" and when the user releases their finger, the chicken jumps. Same concept, but Jump will be different.

```
public float startSpeed;
public float slowAmount;
float actualSpeed;
bool isJumping;

void Awake()
{
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>()["Idle"].wrapMode=WrapMode.Loop;
    gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>() ["TouchDown"].wrapMode = WrapMode.Once;
}

void Start()
{
    GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Idle");
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {
        if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("TouchDown");
        }
        if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended) 
        {
            actualSpeed = startSpeed;
            isJumping = true;
        }
        if (isJumping) 
        {
            actualSpeed -= slowAmount * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position += new Vector3 (0.5f, actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another variable called startY of type float (private).

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.touchCount > 0) {
        if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
            GetComponent<Animation> ().Play ("TouchDown");
        if (Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended){
            actualSpeed = startSpeed;
            isJumping = true;
            startY = transform.position.y;
        }
    }
    if (isJumping) {
        actualSpeed -= slowAmount * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.position += new Vector3 (0, actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        if(startY > transform.position.y) isJumping = false;
    } 
}
```

And change your Update function to this.

Comment: That's what I did in the beginning. It did not work properly too. Exactly the same problem.

Comment: Care to explain the problem?

Comment: I will upload a private link to YouTube.

Comment: transform.position += new Vector3 (0, actualSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);  For some reason you added movement on X axis, set it to zero like I did in answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: See? At 0:06, it does this "mini-jump". And the cube only jumps when you press down (long press) after that.

Comment: The problem with mini jump is you, I am testing it in unity and it works good

Comment: I want the cube to jump when you release the finger, not when you long press.

Comment: I don't care about where the cube goes, that's why I changed the x value.